# Batch delete of multiple lines in multiple files with sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Let's say I want to delete the same lines in a bunch of files. I have a simple bash script like this:

```
st=$1
en=$2
shift 2
for i in $*; do
   echo "sed -i -e '${st},${en}d' $i"
   sed -i -e '${st},${en}d' $i
done
```

which I call like this:

```
[03:18] ./cleanup.sh 2731 3009 trace_X+0.01080_Y+0.00309_Z-0.00000.dat
```

and I get

```
sed -i -e '2731,3009d' trace_X+0.01080_Y+0.00309_Z-0.00000.dat
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried adding more quotes around the variables or the filename in the calling statement but no luck...

Thanks for the help !

Comment: BTW, `$*` is wrong; use `for i in "$@"`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use double quotes in your actual `sed` command:

```
sed -i -e "${st},${en}d" $i
```

There is no variable expansion within single quotes.

The fact that it did expand in the echo is because the string you are echoing is surrounded by double quotes.

And if, in fact, these are only ever numbers you are dealing with, you can even drop quotes completely (`sed -i -e ${st},${en}d`).

Comment: But it does expand it correctly as illustrated by the output of the `echo` call no?

Comment: And so the echo statement expands correctly because of the double quotes on the outside?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That there are single quotes within does not matter, bash only cares about the outer quotes and proceeds to expansion on the whole content between them if they are double quotes. Nothing is ever expanded if the outer quotes are single quotes.